# how do you save video as mp4 on blender?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

i looked up everywhere how to save video as mp4 on blender and im not seeing one post related to it since 2015.... so how?

Comment: Choose MP4 as _File Format_ in the _Output Properties_ instead of PNG, and set the _Encoding_ options to your liking and render the animation with Ctrl+F12. And I don't know where this "everywhere" is you were looking, but entering "blender render mp4" in Google search gave me this as the very first result: [How to Export Video in Blender: MP4 Video Format](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eJmISziyIY) which is 4 months old, definitely not from 2015.

Comment: You need to select ffmpeg before MP4 becomes available.